# ERROR: Out of local stack in my Prolog code

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I cannot figure out why the following query from the given Prolog code generates the error `Out of local stack`.

Prolog code:

```
likes(g,c).
likes(c,a).
likes(c,b).
likes(b,a).
likes(b,d).

likes(X,Z) :- likes(X,Y), likes(Y,Z).
```

the query

```
?- likes(g,X).
```

results in

```
X = c ;
X = a ;
X = b ;
ERROR: Out of local stack
```

**Edit 1** This is the way I think that Prolog should deal with this query,

```
likes(g,c) is a fact, so X={c}
likes(g,b) <= likes(g,c) and likes(c,b), so X={c,b}
likes(g,a) <= likes(g,b) and likes(b,a), so X={c,b,a}
likes(g,d) <= likes(g,b) and likes(b,d), so X={c,b,a,d}
              likes(g,a) and false, so nothing to add to X
              likes(g,d) and false, so nothing to add to X 
end of backtracking search.
```

**Edit 2** I managed to get what I was looking for by the following modification of the code:

```
likes(g,c).
likes(c,a).
likes(c,b).
likes(b,a).
likes(b,d).

indirect_likes(A,B):- likes(A,B).
indirect_likes(A,C):- likes(B,C), indirect_likes(A,B).
```

the query

?- indirect_likes(g,Which).

results in

```
Which = c ;
Which = a ;
Which = b ;
Which = a ;
Which = d ;
false.
```

However, there is still something which I cannot figure out the rationale behind. If I change the last rule to be

```
indirect_likes(A,C):- indirect_likes(A,B), likes(B,C).
```

Then I get `ERROR: Out of local stack`! As far as I know, logical conjunction is commutative.

Comment: Where is `supp/2` defined?

Comment: There is something missing...

Comment: @C.B. I just corrected it. This is part of my longer Prolog code.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10360223/why-does-prolog-crash-in-this-simple-example

Answer (score 3):

To get the [transitive-closure](/questions/tagged/transitive-closure) of binary relation `R_2`, use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure) like so:

```
?- closure(R_2,From,To).
```

Let's run a sample query of `closure/3` together with `likes/2`!

```
?- closure(likes,X,Y).
  X = g, Y = c
; X = g, Y = a
; X = g, Y = b
; X = g, Y = a                    % redundant
; X = g, Y = d
; X = c, Y = a
; X = c, Y = b
; X = c, Y = a                    % redundant
; X = c, Y = d
; X = b, Y = a
; X = b, Y = d
; false.                          % query terminates universally
```

We get the same answers when we use `indirect_likes/2`, but in a different order:

```
?- indirect_likes(X,Y).
  X = g, Y = c
; X = c, Y = a
; X = c, Y = b
; X = b, Y = a
; X = b, Y = d
; X = g, Y = a
; X = g, Y = b
; X = c, Y = a                    % redundant
; X = g, Y = a                    % redundant
; X = c, Y = d
; X = g, Y = d
; false.                          % query terminates universally
```

As you stated in your comments to @C.B.'s answer, binary relations are not necessarily reflexive and/or symmetric. With the definition you gave, `likes/2` is *neither*:

```
?- likes(X,X).
false.                            % not reflexive (not even close)

?- likes(X,Y), likes(Y,X).
false.                            % not symmetric (not even close)
```

---

**So far, so good!**

Let's *tentatively* add the following additional fact to your database:

```
likes(b,b).
```

With this expanded definition, `indirect_likes/2` behaves erratically:

```
?- indirect_likes(b,b).
  true
; true
; true
...                               % does not terminate universally

?- indirect_likes(X,Y), false.    % do we get finite failure?
...                               % no! query does not terminate universally
```

What can we do? Let's use [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  `closure/3` with the expanded version of `likes/2`!

```
?- closure(likes,b,b).
  true                            % succeeds non-deterministically
; false.                          % query terminates universally

?- closure(likes,X,Y), false.     % do we get finite failure?
false.                            % yes! query terminates universally
```

---

**The bottom line?**

In pure Prolog, conjunction is commutative, as far as the logical meaning is concerned.

Due to Prolog's [SLD resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SLD_resolution), the goal `false,repeat` finitely fails, but `repeat,false` does not.
The programmer needs to take care of termination, but usually this is a small price to pay for the raw performance and control that Prolog offers.

In this answer I passed "termination worries" on to the implementor of [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`closure/3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26946133/definition-of-reflexive-transitive-closure)  :)

Answer (score 2):

You spin off into infinite recursion.

Once you get to `likes(b,a)`, you call `likes(a,_G4382)`, which has no fact defined so it switches to the rule `likes(X,Z) :- likes(X,Y), likes(Y,Z).` So it calls `likes(a,_G4383)` which calls `likes(X,Z) :- likes(X,Y), likes(Y,Z).` over and over and over.

You might want to define and auxillary predicate `aux_likes/2` that hosts all your facts. This will only work if there are no circular relationships, i.e. `aux_likes(b,c)` and `aux_likes(c,b)`. You would also need to define `likes(X,X).` This is essentially a graph problem and in graph theory a node has to be connected to itself. If you use it as a generator, it will go off into into infinite recursion (if you have cycles) unless you add `cuts` which are not ideal.

If using `swi-prolog`, feel free to enter the `debug` or `spy` query to see what's going on.

Code:

```
aux_likes(g,c).
aux_likes(c,a).
aux_likes(c,b).
aux_likes(b,a).
aux_likes(b,d).

likes(X,Z) :- aux_likes(X,Y), likes(Y,Z).

likes(X,X).
```

Output with new predicate:

```
?- likes(g,X),print(X),nl,fail.
a
a
d
b
c
g
false.
```

This says `g` can like `a` through `c` or through `b`. It likes `d` through `b`, it likes `b` through `c` and it likes `c` directly. It also must like itself inorder to query like this. If you would rather have the usage mode `(+,+)` meaning you supply it with both terms and no variables (as a checker) you can do

```
?- likes(g,c).
true .
```

Comment: In my code it is possible to have both `likes(a,b)` and `likes(b,a)` at the same time.

Comment: @Rasoul What is the difference between the relationship? is the `likes` predicate directed? i.e. `likes(g,b)` means g likes be but not b likes g?

Comment: `a likes b` does not necessary mean that `b likes a`. `likes` is a directional relationship.

Comment: @Rasoul actually this should work for circular dependencies - I just forgot to add the direct check. See edit above.

Comment: "The output with new predicate" is not complete! It must be `X=a`,`X=b`,`X=c` and `X=d`. I don't see `d` in the answer. BTW! Would you please put the whole modified code in your answer?

Comment: Updated it a bit. Might not be exactly what you want.