# distance between two points in prolog

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to write a code in Prolog to count the distance between two points but when I tried to execute it , it told me that out of local stack
any body know what that means and how i can solve it 
this my code by the way:

```
point(a,5,2).
point(b,4,0).
point(c,2,3).
point(d,5,2).

distance(N1,N2,D) :-
    distance(point(N1,X1,Y2),point(N2,X2,Y2),Z),
    Z=sqrt(((X1-X2)*(X1-X2))+((Y1-Y2)*(Y1-Y2))).

line(N1,N2,D) :-
    distance(N1,N2,Z).

tangent(X,Y,M) :- 
    tangent(point(N1,X1,Y2),point(N2,X2,Y2),M),
    M=(Y1-Y2)/(X1-X2).
```

Answer (score 3):

You are defining `distance` in terms of `distance`. Once there's a query for `distance`, the computer will call `distance`, which will again call `distance`, and so forth. This is known as an [infinite recursion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infinite_recursion).

See also [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20979780/error-out-of-local-stack-in-my-prolog-code).

You should change your code so that the right hand side of

```
distance(N1,N2,D):-distance(point(N1,X1,Y2),point(N2,X2,Y2),Z)
```

does not always refer to the left hand side.

Answer (score 2):

I tried:

```
distance(N1,N2,D) :- point(N1,X1,Y1), 
                     point(N2,X2,Y2),
                     D is sqrt((X2-X1)^2 + (Y2-Y1)^2).
```

ex.

```
?- distance(a,b,D).
D = 2.23606797749979.
```